# Ofice 2013 в Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, office

Здравствуйте! Уже хочется пользоваться новым офисом, а надстройки для Worda в студио работают только для старого офиса. Есть ли возможность работать там с новым офисом? когда выдет новый студио? и можно ли параллельно установить два офиса на худой конец?

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет ссылка [Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=261869)

После установки можно будет выбрать для установки нужные надстройки.